# CSS Grid - span rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to place 2 column's grid divs positioned inline with the 2nd row of divs (see diagram). The total number of rows is dynamic.
[image]

```
 <div class='content'>
  <div class='left'></div>
  <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>    
  </div>
  <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
  </div>
    <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>    
  </div>
  <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
  </div>
    <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>    
  </div>
  <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
  </div>
    <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='right'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 100px 1em;
}
```

why do i need to add text just so I can post this question

Comment: Is this what are you looking for https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2470/?

Comment: in comments you put 7 of these... But I don't count 7 of anything... You want to align columns with rows? That's certainly not right either... Could you try explaining better the grid? Is it always gonna be like this? Should only the top and bottom have fewer cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make this layout by using two grid containers.

A primary grid container will manage the left, center and right items. The center item holds the dynamic content.

A nested container will manage the dynamic content.

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 7fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.column-with-dynamic-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(12%, 1fr)); /* OR...
     grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr); ...which is less responsive, 
                                               but may still work for you. */
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.left {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.right {
  grid-column-end: -1;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}


/* just demo styles */
.left, .right { border: 2px solid red; }
.dynamic { background-color: lightgray; border: 1px solid gray; }
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <div class='left'></div>
  <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='right'></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/juzkxo20/3/)

Comment: I think i wasnt clear with the div layout. I updated the fiddle. Yours is still close, but the grid is row-oriented, whereas I need column: https://jsfiddle.net/juzkxo20/2/